# Viewing android.graphics.bitmaps from hprof dumps

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a dump from hprof that I'm viewing in Eclipse Memory Analyzer.

My hprof shows a particular object that's taking up significantly more memory than I expect.  I'm trying to figure out WHICH bitmap this is.

It turns out that I appear to be able to save the complete dump of the bitmap to a file:

[image]

The resulting file on the filesystem is the full 2,915,840 bytes, so it appears to include all of the bitmap data I should theoretically need in order to view the file.  However, I can't tell what format it's in, or how to convert it.

The output of file and identify is not particularly illuminating:

```
$ file /Users/mike/Desktop/foo.bmp
/Users/mike/Desktop/foo.bmp: data

$ identify /Users/mike/Desktop/foo.bmp 
identify: improper image header `/Users/mike/Desktop/foo.bmp' @ error/bmp.c/ReadBMPImage/590.
```

My question is, what do I need to do in order to view the [resulting file (included here)](http://cl.ly/0M1y1I3F3U2d0n251Q3t) on my mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be here: [MAT (Eclipse Memory Analyzer) - how to view bitmaps from memory dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709603/mat-eclipse-memory-analyzer-how-to-view-bitmaps-from-memory-dump/12709604#12709604)

However, I had some difficulty getting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it appears to be DIB section of bitmap, I'm not familiar with a tool for mac to see a DIB, but you can try to google for it.