# MAT (Eclipse Memory Analyzer) - how to view bitmaps from memory dump

Tags: android, bitmap, memory-dump, hprof, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I'm analyzing memory usage of my Android app with help of [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) (also known as MAT). Sometimes I can find strange instances of `android.graphics.Bitmap` class, utilizing big portion of heap. Problem is what I can't find source of this bitmaps, no *filename*, no *resourceID*, nothing. All information what I can find for bitmap is following:
[image: bitmap_info]

There is a field `mBuffer` with array of image pixels, I assume. But it's in some internal Android format, not PNG.

**Question**: how can I view image represented by this bitmap from memory dump?

Comment: If `mBuffer` is `null`, how can check the value of this member variable of a `Bitmap` in code?

Comment: how did you show the variables values of the bitmap?

Comment: hi mate. I can't find similar window with the information about bitmap in my MAT Eclipse. Where did you find it?

Comment: @Nazerke It is Inspector.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

I have found a way to view such bitmaps:

- First, you need to download and install [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/downloads/)
- Next, find your `Bitmap` object in MAT, right-click on `mBuffer` field, in the popup menu choose *"Copy"* -> *"Save Value To File"* menu item and save value of this array to some file
- give extension `.data` to that file
- launch GIMP, choose *"File"* -> *"Open"*, select your `.data` file and click *Open* button
- *"Load Image from Raw Data"* dialog will appear. Here you need to set correct parameters for your bitmap
- first, choose *"Image type"* as *"RGB Alpha"* (most Android resources have this image type, but you may need to experiment with other image types)
- second, set correct *Width* and *Height* for your bitmap (correct dimensions can be found in the memory dump)

At that point you should already observe preview of original image. If you didn't, you can try to change some other parameters in *"Load Image from Raw Data"* dialog.

NOTE: to get a width and height of image you can look at `mWidth` and `mHeight` fields in MAT in attributes section as shown in image in question.

Comment: This should be upvoted more. This is the most useful thing an Android developer would want. Brilliant!

Comment: For me, mBuffer copy only values, not bytes. 'Copy' works on byte[xxxxx] . Also, to be clear: width X height its spec of tablet. For exemple: I tested this operation on amazon hd8,9 and I have 1200x1920 .

Comment: Edit: it was background image, that why height of tablet was same. For me, its not clear where I can find width and of height of selected byte array

Comment: I have the same question as Sergey: how to know the width and height of the selected img?

Comment: As you can see at first image in the post - there are two fields `mWidth` and `mHeight`

Comment: in eclipse mat where is mBuffer field.plz anybody tell me.

Comment: its in the attributes tab in the Inspector Window. Window>Inspector

Comment: is it possible to open the raw data via the "paint.net" app instead of GIMP ? also, as others have asked, how do you get the width and height of the image?

Comment: How did they get the window which specifies the mHeight and mWidth in the question? I couldn't get it in MAT.

Comment: For those who can't find the window showing `mWidth`-`mHeight`, Goto `Window->Show View->MAT->Inspector`. Select an object in `dominator tree` and in the inspector window you can see the height-width.

Answer (score 6):

You can convert memory dumps from MAT to png using with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) on command line.

In `MAT` for related `Bitmap` object right click `mBuffer` field and select "Copy" -> "Save Value To File", name the file with an `.rgba` extension.

You need to note bitmap width and height from `mWidth` and `mHeight` fields, which you can see in Bitmap object.

Having `ImageMagick` command line tools installed (for Ubuntu `apt-get install imagemagick`), you issue `convert` command with the following parameters.

```
convert -size 'width'x'height' -depth 8 filename.rgba filename.png
```

For example

```
 convert -size 680x1209 -depth 8 phone_decor.rgba phone_decor.png
```

You can check generated png file via [eog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_GNOME), like `eog phone_decor.rgba` on `Ubuntu` easily.