# How to view bitmaps taken from memory dumps?

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, eclipse-memory-analyzer

### Background

android apps usually have a low amount of heap memory for them. that's why you always need to avoid holding large objects.

since the app i'm working on can get OOM on some cases, i thought that i should check out what causes the memory to be low.

i've used [**MAT plugin**](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) and i've found out that the app has 3 bitmaps that take 3.5MB each.

### The problem

the app already has multiple bitmaps being used, but they are way smaller (less than 1MB each).

in fact i've even put breakpoints to make sure each bitmap i create don't take so much memory, and found nothing.

i've also watched some google IO videos (like [**this one**](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/memory-management-for-android-apps.html)) regarding this matter. it seems that in order to see which class has a reference to the object, you click on the object and choose "Path to GC roots"=>"exclude weak references".

### What I've tried

you can see in the dominator-tree which bitmaps take the most (look at "retained heap").

in order to export the data, you can choose the byte array and then "copy"=>"save value to file".

however, like others have tried [**on this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12709604/878126) , i'm stuck at showing the bitmap itself (need to know its format, width and height). plus it could be quite annoying to use GIMP for this task.

### The question

how can i view the bitmaps (the image itself) within eclipse?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709603/mat-eclipse-memory-analyzer-how-to-view-bitmaps-from-memory-dump) for viewing your bitmaps from the heap dump.

Comment: @wsanville isn't there an easier way? within eclipse? also, it seems they didn't answer the question of how to find out the width and height , and i think the created files are much smaller than those that MAT shows (which is weird since they should be RAW).